# What is firmware update data for Elite Dangerous?

Tags: elite-dangerous

After following an "unidentified signal" source, I scanned some data modules and was given a communication of a firmware update. Advising I needed to reboot my system so I went into functions and rebooted but I haven't noticed any differences.
Has anyone come across this before and know what benefits, if any there are?

Comment: Are you playing the just released Beta?

Comment: Also, any chance of getting screen shots?

Comment: Thanks, figured it out. It shows up under the data tab in the materials section to be used by the engineers. I'm playing the X-Box One version and have no idea how to do a screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [data material](https://elite-dangerous.fandom.com/wiki/Data) for Engineers. Data is used for a variety of different engineering upgrades, depending on what specific material you mean (for example, the Charge Enhanced upgrade for a Power Distributor requires Specialized Legacy Firmware).

Data materials can be a mission reward, but they can also come from [surface data sites](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/341987/how-can-i-find-surface-data-points).